# struct parameter to dll gets corrupted

Tags: c, dll, struct

I'm encountering a problem when passing a user-defined type parameter from a c client to a c dll; I have defined the following struct in both client and dll:

```
typedef struct sBar{
  double Open;
  double High;
  double Low;
  double Close;
  char NewDateTime[20];
} tBar;
```

On the client side, I declared the dll function as

```
EXPORT int GetPastBars  (int pDebug, char* pDebugPath[], char* pSymbol[], 
    char* pCurrentTime[], int pTotalBars, char* pTimeFrame[], int pIsFilled, 
    char* pOutputType[],    tBar pPastBars[MAX_HISTORY_DEPTH], 
    tBar pFutureBar[PREDICTION_LENGTH]);
```

Likewise, in the dll source code , the function is declared as:

```
EXPORT int __stdcall GetPastBars(   int pDebug, char* pDebugPath[], char* pSymbol[], 
    char* pCurrentTime, int pTotalBars, char* pTimeFrame[], int pIsFilled, 
    char* pOutputType[], tBar pPastBar[MAX_HISTORY_DEPTH], 
    tBar pFutureBar[MAX_PREDICTION_LENGTH]){
```

I can see that both `pPastBar` and `pFutureBar` are populated correctly right before the end of the dll code; however, when the control gets back to the exe, the first n elements of `pPastBar[]` are zeroed, and n is the difference between `MAX_PREDICTION_LENGTH` (defined in the dll) and `PREDICTION_LENGTH` (defined in the exe).

Any idea?

Comment: 1. include the definition of EXPORT in your question. 2. make sure that the using code and the implementation of your function uses the same prototype in header. So you won't have to post both signatures. 3. If you have the source for EXE and DLL use a debugger.

Comment: Your prototype seems to be missing `__stdcall`

Comment: #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: EXPORT is defined using the same line in both dll and client source code. I am using VS2010 debugger, and that's how I found out that pPastBar and pFutureBar are indeed populated correctly right before the control is passed back from the dll to the client

Comment: I changed the prototype in the client code, adding __stdcall, but that seems to make no difference in the behavior...

Comment: Use a DEF file and you can share the header file between DLL and EXE.

Comment: Hard to believe you can't see this in the debugger.  But surely this was caused by your code filling pFutureBar and *overwriting* part of pPastBar because your are playing this dangerous array size game.  A data breakpoint can do wonders to show you this, set it to the first element of the array.  And fix the function, it needs two more size_t parameters that allow the caller to pass the actual size of the array that it allocated.

Comment: @HansPassant, not only can I see the two arrays correctly filled by  the dll code, but just to be sure I have also used fprintf() to log the various steps involved, so I'm pretty sure the corruption happens when those values are returned to the client. In any case, I'll take your suggestion, and add two size_t parameters to the function prototype.

Comment: @gcaglion What happens is that you fill `pPastBar`, and that looks fine when you do so, but then you fill `pFutureBar` but actually overwrite `pPastBar`. If you fill the arrays before doing your `fprintf` you will see what we mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you did not use the same calling convention on both sides. You clearly need to fix that.

The other problem is that you are likely overrunning the buffers. This is at least in part caused by the confusion evident in your function declarations. You define the argument `pFutureBar` to have one length when compiling the DLL, but then use a different length in your declaration for the executable.

**DLL**

```
tBar pFutureBar[MAX_PREDICTION_LENGTH]
```

**Executable**

```
tBar pFutureBar[PREDICTION_LENGTH]
```

The compiler doesn't care about the length of the array that you specify here and simply passes a pointer to the first element. So what really matters is that the DLL does not access beyond the length of the actual array that you pass.

Although you did not show the code, it seems likely that you passed an array to the `pFutureBar` argument that was too short. And so the DLL wrote beyond the end of it. Very likely you passed an array of length `PREDICTION_LENGTH` and the DLL wrote `MAX_PREDICTION_LENGTH` elements. Assuming that `MAX_PREDICTION_LENGTH` is greater than `PREDICTION_LENGTH` then you have the classic buffer overrun condition.

What you need to do is to change the signature to

```
int __stdcall GetPastBars(..., 
    size_t nPastBar, tBar pPastBar[], 
    size_t nFutureBar, tBar pFutureBar[]
);
```

The new parameters allow the caller to say how large the arrays are that it provides. That in turn enables the callee, the DLL, to avoid writing beyond the end of the buffer as is currently happening.

You can make your life so much easier by using the same header file in the DLL, and in code that calls it. There are many tutorials and examples available that show how to do that. There's no point in my repeating them.

Comment: From the compiler point of view, `void foo(int[])`, `void foo(int[1])` and `void foo(int[10])` is the same signature, namely `void foo(int*)`.

Comment: Yep. I am referring to arrays in function declarations. The top level `[N]` decays to a pointer, regardless of `N`.